# Index scan, Index seek and table scan

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following table:

```
Create table Tab_with_Ix
(
    id int not null,
    name nvarchar(10),
    phone decimal(10,0)
)
```

I inserted some records:

```
insert into Tab_with_Ix 
values(1, 'Yogesh', 8855664452), (2, 'Vinay', 9977884455), (3, 'Sam', 9988554466)
```

Now, I create a non-clustered index on `Tab_with_Ix`:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_Ix on Tab_with_Ix(id)
```

Now, when I query the `Tab_with_Ix`:

```
Select * 
from Tab_with_Ix
where id = 1
```

I get an execution plan as:

[image]

But, when I use the following query:

```
Select id 
from Tab_with_Ix 
where id = 1
```

I get an execution plan as:

[image]

My question is: why does SQL Server use a table scan once, and the other time, an index seek?

Comment: It does it because you have very few rows. If you had thousands, you'd get a different pattern - most likely a index seek and keylookup

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: being nitpicky: since there's no clustered index, it would be a **RID** lookup (not a key lookup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you do a `SELECT *` - you want **all** columns - so in the end, SQL Server must go back to the base table data. In such a case, often it's cheaper to just do a table scan (or clustered index scan) rather than an index seek with an expensive key lookup (or RID lookup, if no clustered index is present).

If you have a lot of rows, then at some point it will become more efficient for SQL Server to do an index scan and a single (or a few) key/RID lookups - so if you have thousands of rows in your sample table - at some point (the "tipping point"), SQL Server will start using your nonclustered index.

In the second case, when you do `SELECT id`, you only want the `id` column - and that column is in the index page - so an index seek on that index will give SQL Server all that it needs to satisfy this query - therefore, an index seek is typically much faster and will be preferred over the table scan.

This is one of the **many reasons** why you should try to avoid using `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table` as much as you can. With a `SELECT *`, more often than not, nonclustered indexes are not used, and a table (or clustered index) scan is used instead.

Comment: so does that means that if i increase the records in the table, the first query will use index seek?

Comment: @vstandsforvinay: if your query fetches a very small percentage of the existing rows (often less than 1%), then yes, SQL Server will typically start using an Index Seek + RID lookup at same point

Comment: less than 1%.. okay!!